# find orthogonal trajectories of the function $y=cx^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is a problem (chapter 1, section 3, 1. b) in the book: Differential equations with applications and historical notes 3rd ed by Simmons.

I differentiate both sides and get:

\begin{align}
dy/dx &= 2cx
\end{align}

So the orthogonal trajectory has a deferential function:
\begin{align}
dy/dx &= -\frac{1}{2cx}\\
y &= -\frac{\log(x)}{2c}
\end{align}

But the answer is: $x^2 + 2y^2 = c^2$.

Could anyone explain how to get the answer?

Comment: From [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question): Your question should be clear without the title. 
After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. **The title is not the first sentence of your question**, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take as many derivatives as there are arbitrary constants in order to get a family.

$y=cx^2$

$\frac{y}{x^2}=c$

$\frac{y'x^2-2xy}{x^4}=0$

$2ydy=-xdx$

$y'=\frac{2y}{x}$

Replace with inverse reciprocal:

$y'=\frac{-x}{2y}$

$2y^2+x^2=c_2$